# Validating Email Using System.Net.Mail.MailAddress Fails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to validate a list of email addresses using the following code:

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddressField() As Boolean
    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    Try
        txtServiceEmails.Text = txtServiceEmails.Text.Trim.Replace(",", ";")
        Dim validateMailAddress = New MailAddress(txtServiceEmails.Text.Trim)
        Return isValid
    Catch ex As Exception
        isValid = False
        Return isValid
    End Try

End Function
```

When I enter "johndoe@amce" or "johndoe@acme, janedoe@acme.org" the code validates true.  Is entering an email address without an extension, such as ".com", actually considered a valid email address?

Thanks,

crjunk

Comment: What's more concerning to you; allowing in invalid email addresses or rejecting valid ones. Cos, practically speaking, those are your only options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an cooperation environment, a domain does not have to have .com/net/org... 'acme' could be a valid domain, so, the email me@acme could be a valid email address internally.

usually, people use regular expression to valid email address. there are lots of examples.

Comment: Validating email addresses properly is hard! I mean really hard. Yes there are lots of examples of regexes for this, but they are almost all wrong in one way or another!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid. The domain part of email address must match the requirements for a hostname  and depending of local configurations the "extension" may be optative.

> A hostname is considered to be a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) if all the labels up to and including the top-level domain name (TLD) are specified. The hostname en.wikipedia.org terminates with the top-level domain org and is thus fully qualified. Depending on the operating system DNS software implementation, an unqualified hostname such as csail or wikipedia may be automatically combined with default domain names configured into the system, in order to determine the fully qualified domain name. **As an example, a student at MIT may be able to send mail to "joe@csail" and have it automatically qualified by the mail system to be sent to joe@csail.mit.edu**.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Do you know of any way I can set MailAddress up so that a host name without an extension is considered invalid? I may have to add some additional code. Trying to get by without using regular expression to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Settled for a Regular Expression Validator solution.

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddressField() As Boolean

    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    Dim emailExpression As New Regex("^((\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\s*[,;:]){1,100}?)?(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$")
    Try
        txtServiceEmails.Text = txtServiceEmails.Text.Trim.Replace(",", ";")
        txtServiceEmails.Text = txtServiceEmails.Text.Trim.Replace(" ", "")
        isValid = emailExpression.IsMatch(txtServiceEmails.Text.Trim)

        Return isValid

    Catch ex As Exception
        isValid = False
        Return isValid
    End Try

End Function
```